# Android Studio - Input Method Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, inputmethodmanager

Android studio version :2.3.3
The code below is not working and it should hide the keyboard but its not.Please help.

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    public void setImm(InputMethodManager imm) {
    this.imm = imm;
    }
    public InputMethodManager getImm() {
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(urledit.getWindowToken(),0);
    return imm;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Hides the soft keyboard
 */
 public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
   if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
   InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) 
 getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
  }
}

 /**
 * Shows the soft keyboard
 */
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
   InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   view.requestFocus();
   inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

Try this to hide and show keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Hope to Useful

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
if (view == null) {
    view = new View(activity);
}
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi use this code and it's working 100%**

```
            View.OnTouchListener disable = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            InputMethodManager img = 
           (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (img != null) {
            img.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
            System.out.println(ee.getSelectionEnd());
            return true;
           }
           };
           //create a Button to setOnTouchListener(event)
           Button ee=new Button(this);
           ee.setOnTouchListener(disable);
```